# Why does the recommended `getExternalStorageState()` to replace deprecated `getExternalStorageDirectory()` not work correctly?

Tags: java, android, filepath, android-external-storage

**Problem:** When I use the recommended `getExternalStorageState()` to replace the deprecated `getExternalStorageDirectory()`, the recommended replacement returns the wrong path. I discovered the issue when the `FileInputStream` crashed, which it wasn't before.

The following is deprecated but correctly returns: */storage/emulated/0/Download/alaina.jpg*

```
return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName;
```

The following is recommended and returns: *mounted/download/alaina.jpg*

```
return Environment.getExternalStorageState() + "/Download/" + fileName;
```

**What I have done:** I've imported and using the class `RealPathUtil` by tatocaster found [here](https://gist.github.com/tatocaster/32aad15f6e0c50311626) and it works great. However, some methods of the `Environment` and `MediaStore` used are now deprecated. The use of `getExternalStorageState()` was recommended through the warnings. I will typically clean up the warnings and use recommendations and this is the first to cause an issue.

The emulator location:

[image]

Comment: `public static String getRealPath(Context context, Uri fileUri) ` Dont use methods like getRealPathFromUri(). It makes no sense. Use the obtained uri directly. This is `recommended` ;-)

Comment: @blackapps - Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > When I use the recommended getExternalStorageState() to replace the deprecated getExternalStorageDirectory(),

That makes no sense as you cannot compare them with each other.

The one delivers a file path. The other a state.

No need to use getExternalStorageState() as it always returns state mounted.

Since years there is always external storage available.

Method getExternalStorageDirectory() works and is undeprecated a week ago.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, that doesn't make sense. I don't think it was recommended through the IDE, I think I misread a source about the `getExternalStorageState()` and misinterpreted it. However, it still returns deprecated, but I will just switch back and leave it. Again, thanks.